# Bash problem: get sum of n lines in a table

Tags: bash

I have this:

```
470 teste/teste1/teste2
202 teste/teste1
135 teste
299 teste
```

As you can see my last 2 lines of 2 column are equal.
What I want is a command that see's every line of 2 column, and if exists lines that are equal, sum the size of all lines in directory.

Basically I want this:

(in my case there are only 2 equal lines but i want something for n lines.)

```
470 teste/teste1/teste2
202 teste/teste1
434 teste
```

Answer (score 1):

With awk:

```
awk '{ a[$2]+=$1 } END{ for(i in a) print a[i],i }' file
```

Output:

```
434 teste
470 teste/teste1/teste2
202 teste/teste1
```

Comment: that table is in a variable ($n2)
Instead of file, can a put $n2?

Comment: Replace `file` by `<<< "$n2"`.

Comment: Ty you a lot!
Can you explain the code? I know what awk does, but i cant understand de array a and the for cicle

Comment: Sorry, I'm an awk newbie and only know how to use Google.

Comment: well ty a lot anyway xD
Where did you find this information?

Comment: Your problem is very similar to an often asked problem. This solution I have derived from my solution there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32811764/3776858